# How to run bunch of hierarchical dummy shell processes (process of another process, etc.)?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, process

I would like to run multiple processes where each process is running another one, so it will create a long process branch.

I've tried:

```
$ bash -c '(bash -c "sleep 20"); sleep 20' &
$ pstree $(pgrep -fn bash)
```

which creates parent and one child process, but is there any trick or easier way of doing that it would generate further 10-20 processes down without struggling with the syntax too much?

Comment: you could try forking and set a limit (e.g. each forked process adds one to an integer count and stops forking at a certain threshold to not forkbomb yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive script. eg in file `/tmp/run`

```
#!/bin/bash
depth=${1:-5}
f(){
 let depth--
 if [ $depth -gt 0 ]
 then $0 $depth
 else sleep 10
 fi
}
f
```

then `chmod +x /tmp/run` and do `/tmp/run 10`.

Comment: Great, I've modified a bit and posted in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079412/55075).